# How to get my Joomla website working with Facebook Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, joomla

I'm running a Joomla 3.4 CMS for my website and I recently enabled gzip and caching in order to speed it up, but now when I post a link to any page on my site from Facebook, it doesn't grab any of the information I'd like to see there (photo, page title, text/description/meta). After doing a bit of research I learned that gzip is known for causing problems with Facebook's bot, so disabled gzip and retested, but it didn't seem to make a difference. I found a plugin (https://github.com/dgt41/facebookfix) and installed it, but that hasn't helped either. I'm at a loss at this point. I'm wondering if maybe something else is going on, but I can't see it. [My website is here.](http://www.holdsworthdesign.com)

Answer (score 0):

These are all OpenGraph Social Meta Tag settings you have to do. Try these inside the `<head>` section of every page. You can use other extension also to do this automatically for you.

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Website Name"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Your Title Here"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Your Description Here" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/image.png" /> 
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/blog/article-name"/>
```